# Why can I execute calc in an SSH session, but not notepad?

Tags: windows, ssh, gui

I'm logged in into a Win32-OpenSSH instance as an administrator in filtered mode (non-elevated) if that matters.

In that session, I learned that I can't run GUI programs because the SSH-server is run in a different session than the same user logged in on the desktop. Security measures will prevent this kind of hijacking of sessions.

And in fact if I try to run "notepad" to edit some file, the notepad window won't show up. But surprisingly, if I run "calc" within the SSH session, the calculator's Window *will* show up on the desktop. Why is that? And what's the mechanism behind it?

Comment: First instinct is that Calculator is a UWP while Notepad isn’t, since I have a feeling, your not using the version of Windows where it is a UWP application

Comment: @Ram what changes if a program is an UWP program regarding the handling of sessions? I use Windows 11

Comment: Install [Windows Notepad](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/windows-notepad/9MSMLRH6LZF3?hl=en-us&gl=us) if you are then able to launch the application, that will prove the common link, is the fact UWP applications are able to be launched over an SSH connection.

Answer (score 0):

According to this
[GitHub Issue](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET/issues/4),
SSH.NET supports UAP 10/UWP as of `SSH.NET 2016.0.0-beta1` from 2016.

This means that user Ramhound is correct in pointing that
"Calculator is a UWP while Notepad isn’t", which explains why
Calculator is working, while classical desktop GUI applications fail.

Comment: Why is that difference between an UWP app and one that is not? Elsewhere people are arguing that not allowing to run notepad within ssh to open a window in another session is a security feature. Why is this feature being circumvented by UWP? And what is the technical implementation?

Comment: The questions.are too general. You can find more about UWP [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/universal-application-platform-guide). Basically, this was Microsoft's latest try at replacing the classical API model of Windows by a framework that will be common to all platforms, not only Windows. This has never caught on, so is generally counted as uninteresting by app developers. Microsoft has rewritten several apps in UWP, such as Explorer and the calculator. The universal flavor of UWP is probably what lets it work in SSH.